# Colocar except com nome do erro em python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, try-finally

Preciso criar um try except, com dois excepts, mas não sei como colocar o erro especifico no primeiro except, o erro que aparece esta abaixo, alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <div class="card-servicos-destaque" ng-style="card.estilo" style="background-color: rgb(237, 28, 36);">...</div> is not clickable at point (136, 346). Other element would receive the click: <div uib-modal-window="modal-window" class="modal fade ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title" aria-describedby="modal-body" index="0" animate="animate" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + $$topModalIndex*10, display: 'block'}" tabindex="-1" uib-modal-animation-class="fade" modal-in-class="in" modal-animation="true" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

E esse:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <button ng-click="vm.irParaHistoricoDeContas()" type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-lg btn-block ng-scope" id="btnSegundaVia" translate="@APP-PAINEL-INICIAL-2-VIA-DE-CONTA">...</button> is not clickable at point (848, 552). Other element would receive the click: <div uib-modal-window="modal-window" class="modal fade ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title" aria-describedby="modal-body" index="0" animate="animate" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + $$topModalIndex*10, display: 'block'}" tabindex="-1" uib-modal-animation-class="fade" modal-in-class="in" modal-animation="true" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: creio que basta colocar a exceção depois do no `except`. No caso a exceção seria `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException`

Answer (score 2):

Então - as exceções que colocamos no comando `except` tem que ser as classes em Python que declaram as exceções, não só os nomes delas, nem só strings.

No caso, o erro te diz em que arquivo ela está declarada:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException

Ou seja, você deve conseguir importa-la no arquivo Python onde vai colocar o try...except com um import como esse no começo do arquivo:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
```

E aí, mais pra baixo no arquivo, onde tiver o `except` pode usar direto o nome `WebDriverException`

```
try:
   # seu código aqui
   ...
except WebDriverException as erro:
   print("Erro - exceção Webdriverexception: ", erro, file=sys.stderr)
...
```

(O print dentro do except é só um exemplo, pode ser qualquer código seu para lidar com o erro).